# How to create a good interface for my class?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, software-design

Is there any good development pattern which I can use to organize my code?

I use C++.

1. I have a base class Command
2. Dozens of classes derived from Command class
3. class Transaction, which stores the array of commands (can be changed)

With current approach the user of Transaction interface should do something like

```
template <typename Base, typename T>
  inline bool instanceof(const T *ptr) {
    return typeid(Base) == typeid(*ptr);
  }

Transaction tx;

// here I want to process all commands
for(int i=0; i < N; i++){
  if(instanceof<AddPeer>(tx.get(i)) {
   // ... process
  }
  if(instanceof<TransferAsset>(tx.get(i)) {
   // ... process
  }
  ... for every type of command, but I have dozens of them
}
```

---

```
class Command;
class TransferAsset: public Command {}
class AddPeer: public Command {}
// dozens of command types

class Transaction{
public:
  // get i-th command
  Command& get(int i) { return c[i]; }
private:
  // arbitrary collection (of commands)
  std::vector<Command> c;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why, simply, Command has not a virtual pure method to implement in derived classes?
Something like this:

```
class Command
{ virtual void process () =0;};
class TransferAsset: public Command 
{ 
   void process ()
   {
     //do something 
   }
};
class AddPeer: public Command    
{ 
   void process ()
   {
     //do something 
   }
};
```

You code could be then:

```
Transaction tx;
// here I want to process all commands
for(int i=0; i < N; i++)
{
   tx.get(i)->process();
}
```

Comment: If processing of a command is hard (lots of code), then it is probably bad to give this processing logic directly to `process` method. I am thinking about `class Processor`, which will be passed to `void process(Processor &e)`. Is it good design?